# How to collapse react-bootstrap accordion panel horizontally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am working with the Panel component from React-Bootstrap page here - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/panel/ - and i would like to use their accordion feature with the caveat that the panel body's (Panel.Body) opens horizontally (open to the right of the Panel.Headings that are shown).

Here is one of the examples from their page:

```js
const PanelGroup = ReactBootstrap.PanelGroup;
const Panel = ReactBootstrap.Panel;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PanelGroup accordion id="accordion-uncontrolled-example">
        <Panel style={{ display: 'flex' }} eventKey="1">
          <Panel.Heading style={{ margin: '0 2% 0 0' }}>
            <Panel.Title toggle>Panel heading 1</Panel.Title>
          </Panel.Heading>
          <Panel.Body collapsible>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </Panel.Body>
        </Panel>
        <Panel style={{ display: 'flex' }} eventKey="2">
          <Panel.Heading style={{ margin: '0 2% 0 0' }}>
            <Panel.Title toggle>Panel heading 2</Panel.Title>
          </Panel.Heading>
          <Panel.Body collapsible>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </Panel.Body>
        </Panel>
        <Panel style={{ display: 'flex' }} eventKey="3">
          <Panel.Heading style={{ margin: '0 2% 0 0' }}>
            <Panel.Title toggle>Panel heading 3</Panel.Title>
          </Panel.Heading>
          <Panel.Body collapsible>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </Panel.Body>
        </Panel>
      </PanelGroup>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.32.1/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id='root'>
  Come On Work!
</div>
```

I have added `display: flex` to wrap the panels, although I am not getting the desired layout here. **Rather** than extending inline, with the body having the same vertical flush as **its own** heading, I would like it if the panel was always vertically flush with Panel Heading 1, regardless of which panel it was that was clicked open.

Additionally, I would like for the Panel Heading to remain the same width, rather than crunch up to a very small width, when the panel is opened.

Clearly I'm not sure if react-bootstrap Panel component is the right tool for this, or if i should create my own custom horizontal accordion tool (not quite sure how to do that though). That is part of what I am asking as well!

Thanks as always for any help.

Comment: simply adding a style with display: flex to the Panel is a good start - but it still does not look correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well created this working snippet where the panels work like in react-bootstrap examples.

But not sure if I understand what exactly you look for visually?

you want instead of slide down effect when toggling to have a slide right?

how exactly? you have the panel title as a block so where the content will fit in?

```js
const PanelGroup = ReactBootstrap.PanelGroup;
const Panel = ReactBootstrap.Panel;


class PanelHorizontal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    const classesNames = ['panelHorizontal'];
    if (this.state.visible){
      classesNames.push('slideIn');
    } else {
      classesNames.push('slideOut');
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1
          className="title"
          onClick={()=>this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible})}
        >click to toggle</h1>
        
        <div className={classesNames.join(' ')}>
          content here
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PanelHorizontal />
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.panelHorizontal {
  width: 220px;
  transform: translateX(-220px);
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in;
}
.panelHorizontal.slideIn {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.panelHorizontal.slideOut {
  transform: translateX(-220px);
}

.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.32.1/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id='root'>
  Come On Work!
</div>
```

Comment: > how exactly?

That is my question yes. It seems like the <Panel> react-bootstrap component is not built in a way that makes it easy to make this a horizontal accordion.

Comment: This is not built for toggling horizontally :/ so u probably need to create it by yourself...

Comment: How do i go about coding up the collapsing effect? Is that simply an on click handler?

Comment: updated my code snippet, now you have a super simple example of horizontal toggle

Comment: I am new to javascript and web dev and my mind is so focused on trying to find / use prebuilt components from react-bootstrap / other react-'name' packages for my react app that i forget that some of this stuff can be built with vanilla JS, css and html.

Will likely accept this answer, thank you for thoughts on this.

Comment: Yap it's always better to use someone else's work. But this small component could be what you need just redesign it to and you are good to go. Ask away if you are stuck

Comment: Yes if i get stuck when building this myself i will certainly post